# Better approach on updating a datarow with a bindingsource?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I'm having a problem where I have created a new DataRow and then trying to update the DataRow using a Bindingsource on a winform, but it's not happening,

**....and yes**, I have tried using OnPropertyChanged but with no joy.

Here's the scenario... I have this bit of code:

```
dim dr as DataRow

dr = TheDataSet.TheTable.NewTheTableDataRow
TheDataSet.TheTable.Rows.Add(dr)
TheTableBindingSource.MoveLast()
```

Where the TheDataSet was configured using the wizard connecting to a Microsof SQL Server 2008.

Now when I assign something to the datarow like

```
   dr("Comment") = "Some Text"
```

That's fine when I do an TheTableTableAdapter.Update(Me.TheDataSet) and that part updates the fields in the SQL server; However, I got textboxes, checkboxes, and comboboxes on the form that is bound to the BindingSource, yet any changes I do with them does not get committed to the dataset, hence not updated to the server.

So, what am I doing wrong? I need to use the "dr" DataRow so I can make some business logic data that is not handled by the user, yet it needs to be populated of whatever from the user input on the form (like changing the model number configuration string from a checkboxes that are ticked)

How can I do both?

**EDIT:** Yes, the DataSource of the BindingSource is indeed assigned to the dataset, and the DataMember is assigned to the correct table in the server.

Comment: Where's the love guys? Any takers?

Comment: I am guessing that there is no 'love' because you haven't given us enough code...